# Добавление иконки с масштабом в google maps android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Ни в примерах, ни в документации не нашел о том как добавить на экран информацию о масштабе. В стандартном приложении справа снизу она отображается. Как можно добавить такую функцию в свой проект? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Держи https://github.com/pengrad/MapScaleView

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 0):

[Согласно официальной документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls?hl=ru)

Вы можете добавлять соответствующую кнопку на карте следующим методом

```
UiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Это добавляет кнопки - "+", "-". Увеличение, уменьшение масштаба карты, а не саму величину масштаба.